# Make sure that HomePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider<ProductProvider>. This usually happens when you are creating a

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**When I sing in from HomePage this happen**

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this HomePage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that HomePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

**this is my main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cor/%20crud/addproduct.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cor/home/homepage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cor/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cor/providers/product_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cor/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cor/signup.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

import 'ProductOverview.dart';
import 'Colors.dart';

bool islogin;

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (user == null) {
  islogin = false;
} else {
  islogin = true;
}
runApp( MaterialApp(

    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: new MyApp(),
    theme: ThemeData(

        primaryColor: prColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white))),
    routes: {
      "login": (context) => Login(),
      "signup": (context) => SignUp(),
      "homepage": (context) => HomePage(),
      "addproduct": (context) => AddProduct(),
      "productOverview" :(context)=> ProductOverview(),
    }));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return   SplashScreen(
      useLoader: false,
      seconds: 7,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      image: new Image.asset("images/market.gif"),
      photoSize: 220,
      navigateAfterSeconds: ForSplash(),
    );

}
}

class ForSplash extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MultiProvider(providers: [
  ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductProvider>(
  create: (context)=>ProductProvider(),),

    ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
      create: (context)=>UserProvider(),),

  ],
  child: Builder(
    builder:(BuildContext newContext){
     return  islogin == false? Login():HomePage();
    }
  )

  );
}
}
```

I dont understand what doing please help me

Comment: the above code is not where the error is. But I believe the error message probably gives you enough information to solve the error. your provider is probably on the wrong route. To fix it, move the multi-provider above the material app.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.